# Moving models to separate project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to move my models to  a separate project in my ASP.NET MVC 3 application. Everything work fine with the exception of one file where I get the error -

> The type or namespace name 'Compare' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   The type or namespace name 'CompareAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The references in the new project are exactly the same as the references in the original MVC project but when this one file is moved to the new project it gives the errors above.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: I think it's in `System.Web.Mvc` (the assembly/dll) although it kind of seems like it's in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. Thing is, you probably don't want to have a reference to `System.Web.Mvc` in your model class (not saying you should or shouldn't, just that you probably actively don't want to).

Comment: Why, oh why do you need to move your models to a separate project? What do you gain by doing so?

Comment: I've seen it done in cases where there's a Web project and a MobileWeb project.  Both projects hit the same DLL for the business logic and such.

Comment: @Oded I'm just following examples on the new Pluralsight course by Dan Wahlin (Building ASP.NET MVC Apps with EF Code First, HTML5, and jQuery) and that's how it is set up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CompareAttribute` Class is part of the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace.  Make sure you have that assembly as a reference in your project (in *Solution Explorer* -> *References*), and also make sure you have:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

At the top of your source file.

[MSDN Reference on the `CompareAttribute` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.compareattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx):

**Namespace**:  System.Web.Mvc
**Assembly**:  System.Web.Mvc (in System.Web.Mvc.dll)

Comment: That's the strange thing. I have the assembly as a reference in both my models project and my regular MVC project. I also have the using statement in the source file. When I have the file in the m,odels folder of the MVC project it works but when I move it to the models project it errors.

Comment: I've got it working now. I removed the reference to System.Web.Mvc in the models project and then readded it again.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a reference to a component/namespace it can be useful to expand or resize the Add Reference window to see all the additional column information, such as Version, Runtime and Path. In response to the above, you may had reference System.Web.Mvc prior to MVC 3 in which the CompareAttribute hadn't been introduced.

Try sorting the Component Name column and check for duplicate entries with different Version, Runtime and Path values. This can be true if you have more than one .NET Framework installed. Ensure that you choose the correct version that supports what you need. In this case selecting System.Web.Mvc Version 3.0.0.0 or above would have included the CompareAttribute that you were after.

Kind regards